# The functions "getsMarks" and "getTimescaleMarks" are not invoked within the JS API of the TradingView charting library with custom datafeed

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I have effectively created a customized data feed and achieved data retrieval. My current objective is to incorporate markers onto the data points for dividends and annual meetings. I've submitted all the relevant code, including getMarks and getTimescaleMarksbfunctions. However, upon inspection using console.log(), I've noticed that there is no output displayed for these functions. I'm seeking assistance from anyone who can help me resolve this particular issue.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>TradingView Charting Library example</title>
<script src="charting_library_cloned_data/charting_library/charting_library.js"></script>
</head>

    <body style="margin:0px;">
        <!-- A container for the Charting Library widget -->
        <div id="tv_chart_container">
        </div>
    
<script>


const configurationData = {
    supported_resolutions: ['D', 'W','M'],
};

async function getAllSymbols() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://x.x.x.x/technicalChart/exchange.php`);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        const data = Array.isArray(jsonData) ? jsonData : [jsonData]
        let allSymbols = [];
        const symbols = data.map(item => {
            return {
                symbol: item.symbol,
                full_name: item.full_name,
                description: item.description,
                exchange: item.exchange,
                type: item.type,
                stock_name:item.stock_name,
            };
        });
        allSymbols = [...allSymbols, ...symbols];
        return allSymbols;
    } catch(error) {
        throw new Error(`Symbol Information is not available: ${error}`);
    }
}


const datafeed = {
    onReady: (callback) => {
        console.log('[onReady]: Method call');
       setTimeout(() => callback(configurationData));
    },

    searchSymbols: async (
        userInput,
        exchange,
        symbolType,
        onResultReadyCallback
    ) => {
        console.log('[searchSymbols]: Method call');
        const symbols = await getAllSymbols();
        const newSymbols = symbols.filter(symbol => {
            const isExchangeValid = exchange === '' || symbol.exchange === exchange;
            const isFullSymbolContainsInput = symbol.full_name
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(userInput.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
            return isExchangeValid && isFullSymbolContainsInput;
        });
        
        onResultReadyCallback(newSymbols);
    },

    resolveSymbol: async (
        symbolName,
        onSymbolResolvedCallback,
        onResolveErrorCallback,
        extension
    ) => {
        console.log('[resolveSymbol]: Method call  check', symbolName);
        const symbols = await getAllSymbols();
        const symbolItem = symbols.find(({ full_name }) => full_name === symbolName);
        if (!symbolItem) {
            console.log('[resolveSymbol]: Cannot resolve symbol', symbolName);
            onResolveErrorCallback('Cannot resolve symbol');
            return;
        }
        // Symbol information object
        const symbolInfo = {
            ticker: symbolItem.full_name,
            name: symbolItem.symbol,
            description: symbolItem.description,
            type: symbolItem.type,
            session: '24x7',
            timezone: 'Asia/Ashkhabad',
            //exchange: symbolItem.exchange,
            exchange: symbolItem.stock_name,
            
            minmov: 1,
            pricescale: 100,
            has_intraday: false,
            //has_no_volume: false,
            has_weekly_and_monthly: false,
            supported_resolutions: configurationData.supported_resolutions,
            volume_precision: 2,
            //data_status: 'streaming',
        };
        console.log('[resolveSymbol]: Symbol resolved  changed', symbolName);
        onSymbolResolvedCallback(symbolInfo);
    },

    getBars: async (symbolInfo, resolution, periodParams, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback) => {
        const { from, to, firstDataRequest } = periodParams;
        var exchange ="PSX"
        const urlParameters = {
            e: exchange,
            fsym: symbolInfo.full_name,
            tsym: symbolInfo.full_name,
            toTs: to,
            limit: 4819,
        };
        const query = Object.keys(urlParameters)
            .map(name => `${name}=${encodeURIComponent(urlParameters[name])}`)
                .join('&');
        try {
            
            const response = await fetch(`http://x.x.x.x/technicalChart/histoday1.php?${query}`);
            const data = await response.json();
            let bars = [];
            const bar = data.map(item => {
                return {
                    time: item.time,
                    low: item.low,
                    high: item.high,
                    open: item.open,
                    close: item.close,
                    volume: item.volume,
                };
            });
            bars = [...bars, ...bar];
            onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('[getBars]: Get error', error);
            onErrorCallback(error);
        }
    },

    subscribeBars: (symbolInfo, resolution, onRealtimeCallback, subscriberUID, onResetCacheNeededCallback) => {
        console.log('[subscribeBars]: Method call with subscriberUID:', subscriberUID);
    },
    unsubscribeBars: (subscriberUID) => {
        console.log('[unsubscribeBars]: Method call with subscriberUID:', subscriberUID);
    },
            /* getMarks add new addition */
        
    getMarks: async (symbolInfo, startDate, endDate, onDataCallback, resolution) => {
           console.log("get marks value")
         console.log(symbolInfo, startDate, endDate)
          marks =[
                  {
                    "id": 1,
                    "time": 1689274800000,
                    "color": "blue",
                    "text": "Dividend announced",
                    "label": "B",
                    "labelFontColor": "yellow",
                    "minSize": 20,
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 2,
                    "time": 1688583600000,
                    "color": "red",
                    "text": "Annaul Meeting",
                    "label": "G",
                    "labelFontColor": "black",
                    "minSize": 20,
                  },
                ]

          // Callback to the TradingView library.
          onDataCallback(marks);
        },
        
        getTimescaleMarks: (symbolInfo,startDate,endDate,onDataCallback,resolution) => {
            console.log("getTimescaleMarks:");
            console.log(symbolInfo,startDate,endDate)
            onDataCallback([   
                      {
                        id: 1,
                        time:  1689274800000,
                        color: 'Turquoise',
                        label: 'D',
                        minSize: 20,
                        tooltip:[
                          "Information you want to print",
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        id: 2,
                        time: 1688583600000 , // 2 months
                        color: 'blue',
                        label: 'A',
                        minSize: 30,
                        tooltip: [
                            'Amet',
                            'Consectetur',
                            'Adipiscing',
                            'Elit',
                        ]
                    }
                    ]);
            }


        
};


 function initOnReady() {
   
   var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
    symbol: 'POL',            // Default symbol pair
    interval: 'D',                        // Default interval
    fullscreen: true,                      // Displays the chart in the fullscreen mode
    container: 'tv_chart_container',       // Reference to an attribute of a DOM element
    datafeed: datafeed,

    library_path: 'charting_library_cloned_data/charting_library/',
     timezone: 'Asia/Ashkhabad',
     drawings_access: { type: 'black', tools: [{ name: "Regression Trend" }] },
     disabled_features: [ "volume_force_overlay", "study_templates"],
     overrides: {
                        "volumePaneSize": "medium",
                        "mainSeriesProperties.style": 1,
                        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.upColor": "#00e100",
                        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.downColor": "#ff0000",
                        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.borderColor": "#666666",
                        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.borderUpColor": "#666666",
                        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.borderDownColor": "#666666",
                        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.wickUpColor": "#666666",
                        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.wickDownColor": "#666666",
                        "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.wickColor": "#666666"
                    },
                    enabled_features: ["context_menus", "pane_context_menu", "items_favoriting", "use_localstorage_for_settings", "side_toolbar_in_fullscreen_mode"],
            favorites: {
                        intervals: ["1D", "1W", "1M"],
                        chartTypes: ["Candles", "Line", "Heiken Ashi"]

                    },
            time_frames:[
    {text:'10y' ,resolution: 'W', description:'10 Year'},
    {text:'5Y' ,resolution: 'W', description:'5 year'},
    {text:'1Y' ,resolution: 'D', description:'1 year'},
    {text:'6M' ,resolution: 'D', description:'6 month'},
    
    ],
    time: 1630368000,   

});


widget.headerReady().then(function () {
                    function createHeaderButton(text, title, clickHandler, options) {
                        var button = widget.createButton(options);
                        button.setAttribute('title', title);
                        button.textContent = text;
                        button.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
                        if (text === '+') {
                            button.textContent += ' Compare';
                          }
                    }
                    createHeaderButton('Clear Marks', '', function () {
                        widget.chart().clearMarks();
                    });

                    createHeaderButton('Load Marks', '', function () {
                        widget.chart().refreshMarks();
                    });
                    createHeaderButton('Remove All Studies', '', function () {
                        widget.chart().removeAllStudies();
                    });

                    createHeaderButton('Remove All Shapes', '', function () {
                        widget.chart().removeAllShapes();
                    });
                    
                     
                });

        };
 
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initOnReady, false);
  

</script>
</body>
</html
```

> 

Answer (score 0):

I updated the configurationData by adding supports_marks to true. The current configurationData now looks like this:

```
const configurationData = {
    supported_resolutions: ['D', 'W','M'],
    supports_marks:true,    
};
```

However, there's still an issue with marks not being displayed on the chart. What additional configuration changes should I consider to make the marks visible on the chart?